# Killing form of a Lie algebra of matrix

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra (with field $F$). Consider the killing form
$$\begin{align*} k:&L \times L \to F \\
&(x,y) \to Tr(ad(x)ad(y))
\end{align*}$$
We know that $L$ is semisimple if and only if its killing form is non degenerate.

Now If $L \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, I can define
$$\begin{align*} k’:&L \times L \to F \\
&(x,y) \to Tr(xy)
\end{align*} $$
I want to prove: $L$ is semisimple if and only if $k’$ is non degenerate. One implication is trivial:

Suppose $L$ semisimple. If $x\in L^{\bot}$(respect $k’$) and $y\in L$ then $Tr(xy)=0$, so in particular this is true for $y \in [L^\bot,L^\bot]$. So, by Cartan’s criterion, $L^\bot$ is solvable and so it is zero since $RadL=0$.

I don’t know how to complete the other implication. My idea is to replicate the proof of the general case (Humphreys pg 22).

Some ideas?

Comment: Your [previous example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722454/prove-that-a-lie-algebra-is-semisimple) of $L$ was a *simple* Lie algebra, namely $\mathfrak{sp}(2n)$. Then, by Schur's Lemma, the Killing form is a nonzero scalar multiple of the Killing form, hence the trace form is non-degenerate. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798995/killing-form-on-mathfraksp2n).

Comment: For the first part, the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{psl}_n(\Bbb F)$, where $\Bbb F$ has characteristic $p$ dividing $n>2$, has a degenerate trace form.

Comment: Note that you could have noticed the implication you asked about is false, by just looking at the basic case $L=F =\mathfrak{gl}(F)$. Checking examples is generally the first thing one should do if one is stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace form of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$ is nondegenerate over a field $F$ of characteristic zero. However, $\mathfrak{gl}_n(F)$ is not semisimple. So the converse is not true.

However, it is known, see Bourbaki's book on Lie algebras, that a Lie algebra $L$ having a nondegenerate trace form for some representation is *reductive*. For references see this post:

[Killing form of a reductive symmetric Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237504/killing-form-of-a-reductive-symmetric-lie-algebra)

Also, if you require that *all* trace forms $B_{\rho}$ of $L$ are nondegenerate, then $L$ is semisimple, See this post:

[Semisimplicity of Lie algebras and non-degeneracy of associated bilinear forms of representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980952/semisimplicity-of-lie-algebras-and-non-degeneracy-of-associated-bilinear-forms-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)